# convert Excel to csv either using shell script or jython . if so how

Tags: shell, jython

I am looking for a procedure where i can convert the excel to csv either if there some shell script , if so please guide me or if possbile how can i do in jython.

The main reason is that the excel is being received from other source and the header is always changing , which is unnecessary and we need to have some automatic way to remove that . If is it possible to do that easily using jython or shell script and remove only the first line of the excel

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To convert between various file formats I use: [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter). There is Python and Java version.

It uses OpenOffice working as a service and can convert between various document formats including MS Office, PDF and text.

There is also pure Python library: [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) *Library for developers to extract data from Microsoft Excel (tm) spreadsheet files*